# CreateProcess can not run sfc.exe ? why

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Using CreateProcess to create a process that running the sfc.exe.  However, no effect.
I have Administrator Permission to run this program

I use CreateProcess API to control the CUI ouput and catch the CUI programs output info.

I want to recv sfc /scannow commands output by using pipe and

```cpp
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    HANDLE hReadPipe = NULL;
    HANDLE hWirtePipe = NULL;
    if (!CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWirtePipe, &sa, NULL)) {
        std::cout << "create pipe failed \n";
        return -1;
    } 


    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW|STARTF_USESTDHANDLES,
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    si.hStdError = hWirtePipe;
    si.hStdOutput = hWirtePipe;

    TCHAR szCommand[] = TEXT("sfc /scannow");
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, szCommand, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) 
    {
        cout << "process create failed ,errno is ："<< GetLastError() << endl;
        CloseHandle(hReadPipe);
        CloseHandle(hWirtePipe);
        return -1;
    }
    
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    DWORD stdRead = 0;
    DWORD total;
    DWORD timeout = 50;
    TCHAR bufferOutPipe[1024] = {0};
    TCHAR readBuffer[1024] = {0};
    BOOL flag = true;
    while (flag) {
        if (WAIT_TIMEOUT == WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, timeout)) {
            if (!PeekNamedPipe(hReadPipe, bufferOutPipe, 1024, &dwRead, &total, 0) || dwRead <= 0) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                ReadFile(hReadPipe, readBuffer, dwRead, &stdRead, NULL);
                printf("%s\n", readBuffer);
                dwRead = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, timeout)) {
            if (PeekNamedPipe(hReadPipe, bufferOutPipe, 1024, &dwRead, &total, 0) && dwRead > 0) {

                ReadFile(hReadPipe, readBuffer, dwRead, &stdRead, NULL);
                printf("%s\n", readBuffer);
            }
            flag = false;
        }
        ZeroMemory(readBuffer, 1024);
    }
    CloseHandle(hReadPipe);
    CloseHandle(hWirtePipe);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
```

I want to receive the output of the 'SFC / scannow' command and redirect the output by using anonymous pipes and processes, but I can't hear any pipe data, and the created process is launched immediately,

I started visual studio with administrator

Comment: Could you post some of your code that is starting `sfc.exe`? Does it work with another program such as `calc.exe`?

Comment: yea, some tools can start-up by CreateProcess , eg :Dism.exe

Comment: What programming language is this? C++? Adding a tag for the language will improve the visibility of your question and probably lead to more useful answers.

Comment: I got your example working by removing the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag. (Ofc, you have some missing elements in your snippet, like the declaration of `processInfo`). You also need to call `CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess)` and `CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread)` at the end.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I want to point out that the process created by CreateProcess can't get the output of SFC. Strangely, I use dism /? Instead of SFC / scan now, it has output information

Comment: @Marius Bancila: my puzzle is that there is no data to redirect “SFC / scannow ”output, but the same code can redirect “dism /？”

Answer (score 0):

`si.hStdInput` is not initialized to a valid value. 0 is not valid. You appear to want `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

With `FALSE` for `bInheritHandles`, your output redirection won't work anyway. This appears to be your current root problem.

In addition, your code will spin forever once the process opens because `CloseHandle(hWirtePipe);` isn't called in a timely manner but after the loop instead. Then tend to your handle leaks.

Now for that wait loop. Yuck. The normal construction is to read until the end of the pipe, and only then wait for the process to exit. As the loop stands you have a race condition that will cause you to (most likely) lose the tail end of the output. Note that this will block forever until you close your copy of the write end before entering the loop. You don't need any of that PeekWhatever nonsense either. Just ReadFile the handle until you get the specific error for end of pipe.

Comment: I've updated my code. When the process ends ,WaitForSingleObject will return WAIT_OBJECT_0

Comment: @Marsontao_: You shouldn't call `WaitForSingleObject` multiple times inside the loop.  Instead save the return value, and compare that one return value to both `WAIT_TIMEOUT` and `WAIT_OBJECT_0`

Comment: @Joshua: You mean reading pipes asynchronously ?

Comment: @Marsontao_: Actually I mean synchronously. ReadFile will block until there's something to read.

Comment: @Joshua: I seriously think about your above guidance. I'm sorry I'm stupid, but I still don't understand it.Moreover, my puzzle is that there is no data to redirect “SFC / scannow ”output, but the same code can redirect “dism  /？”command

Comment: @Marsontao_: Probably, buffering. Quite a few MS programs use some innane default standard output setting where if the output target isn't a terminal it spools up several KB before emitting a single byte. But not all of them.